# "the safe door must be open to call command WFS_CMD_CDM_DISPENSE!"

Tags: xfs, cen-xfs

This is the message i got when i tried to dispense money from Wincr Nixdorf ATM by using CDM320.exe which is a built-in tool of the ATM. In general, the safe door of an ATM must be closed for dispense to be done successfully. I don't know where this message has come from!
I wrote a source code for dispensing via XFS 3.00 API. It works on GSS ATM, but it doesn't work on the Wincor ATM.
How can i make sure that everything in the Wincor ATM is properly configured and working, like SPI, MSXFS.DLL file is good-versioned and properly works and everythings are compatible to work together? Since the CDM tester tool is not working, i doubt in the ATM itself instead of my program.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the Wincor manual(s) how to configure the CDM device to your expected behavior model.

This particular instance could indicate that the dispenser/ATM is in test mode and thus doesn't allow dispense unless the safe door is open (and possibly even the dispenser should be out of the safe).

Or maybe the error message is missing a work 'NOT' and your safe is not properly locked.
Even in this case the CDM configuration should do the trick.

PS. I don't have experience from Wincor HW so this might be totally off the mark as my experience come's from NCR HW.